# python, writing Json to file

Tags: python, json, file

I'm trying to write my first json file. But for some reason, it won't actually write the file. I know it's doing something because after running dumps, any random text I put in the file, is erased, but there is nothing in its place. Needless to say but the load part throws and error because there is nothing there. Shouldn't this add all of the json text to the file?

```
from json import dumps, load
n = [1, 2, 3]
s = ["a", "b" , "c"]
x = 0
y = 0

with open("text", "r") as file:
    print(file.readlines())
with open("text", "w") as file:
    dumps({'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, file, indent=4)
file.close()

with open("text") as file:
    result = load(file)
file.close()
print (type(result))
print (result.keys())
print (result)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [`json.dump()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) method:

```
with open("text", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump({'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, outfile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 11):

Change:

```
dumps({'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, file, indent=4)
```

To:

```
file.write(dumps({'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, file, indent=4))
```

Also:

- don't need to do `file.close()`. If you use `with open...`, then the handler is always closed properly.
- `result = load(file)` should be `result = file.read()`